# Store custom class with core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to store data of a custom type with core data.
My class (friendItem) has one property (friend) of type NSData, to store it.

After archiving every elements of my array of type KNSelectorItem to NSData, I store them as "friend" in friendItem. But when I want to unarchive every elements of my array to read the information as KNSelectorItem objects, I get this error:

> -[FriendItems bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a637dc0

Code that might help:

**HomeViewController.m**

```
    -(void)selector:(KNMultiItemSelector *)selector didFinishSelectionWithItems:(NSArray  *)selectedItems
    {
      for (KNSelectorItem * i in selectedItems) {
      NSLog(@"ID: %@ NAME: %@", i.selectValue, i.displayValue);
      NSData *friendtosave = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:i];
     [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        FriendItems *friend = [FriendItems MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
        friend.friend = friendtosave;
     }];

    }
```

**In ViewDidLoad of HomeViewController.m**

```
    NSArray *friendsdata = [FriendItems MR_findAll];
    NSLog(@"friends saved as data %@", friendsdata);

    NSMutableArray *unarchievedFriends = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSData *i in friendsdata)
    {
        KNSelectorItem *friendDecrypted = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:i];
        [unarchievedFriends addObject:friendDecrypted]; // THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS WHEN CHECKING WITH BREAKPOINTS
        NSLog(@"friend decrypted : %@", friendDecrypted.displayValue);

    }
```

What did I do wrong ? What did I miss ?

PS: I'm using [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) to manage my core data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unarchiving code does not make use of the `friends` relationship. You never look up the encoded data, you try to unarchive the `FriendItems` object directly. In the second code snippet:

- `friendsdata` is an array of `FriendItems`
- You iterate over that array, which means that `i` is actually a `FriendItems` instance.
- You try to unarchive `i`, which is not an `NSData`, so you get the error you're seeing.

Based on what you've said, you need to change the loop to

```
for (FriendItems i in friendsdata) {
```

And then unarchive `i.friendsdata` instead of `i`.

Comment: Ok, now it works like a charm, thanks !
(it still doesn't show on my selected items after I come back to the view controller, but it might come from another problem i'll dig into, at least now it unarchives fine)